# Crow's Foot Diagrams on Windows

Tags: windows, diagram, er-diagram

I've been using Visio to create [Crow's Foot Diagrams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-diagram-with-crow-s-foot-database-notation-1ec22af9-3bd3-4354-b2b5-ed5752af6769).

What are other good Windows 10 alternatives to create such diagrams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view, the most practical general purpose alternative is [draw.io](https://drawio-app.com/entity-relationship-diagrams-with-draw-io/).

It is not only free of charge but also offers a web version which means users aren't confined to a specific operating system.

Here is what you can do with it:

- *Entity relationship diagram with basic shapes representing the relationships.*
  [image: Entity relationship diagram with basic shapes representing the relationships]
- *The same diagram in a different style – with attributes listed inside the entities themselves.*

[image: The same diagram in a different style – with attributes listed inside the entities themselves]

---

Additionally, when dealing with databases in PostgreSQL, often prefer to use [pgAdmin 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66103248/5675325) since I'm already using it for the database itself and the diagrams are easier to keep updated.

[image]